# Splitting a txt file into several variables with nodejs

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, string, parsing

I have the following types of files which I read synchronously with node.js :

```
THIS IS A HEADLINE 

12.X. p. 200
Bla. - blabla. - blablablala. - Some more bla. -
Bla. - Some blaa. - blabla. - Some extra bla. -
Bla. - blabla. - blablablala. - Some more bla. -
Bla. - blabla. - blablablala.

12.XI. p. 202
blabla. - blablablala. - Some more bla. -
Bla. - bla. - blablala. - Some more bla. -
Bla. - Some blaa. - blabla. - Some more bla. -
Bla. - blabla. - blablablala. - Some more bla. -
Bla. - blbla. - blablablala. -
```

I would now like to parse this file. I would like to have the headline in one variable, the id number (12.X.), the page number (p. 200) and the data (Bla, blabla and so on) in an array.

So in the end everything would kind of look like:

```
{ 
 headline: "THIS IS A HEADLINE",
 1: { id: "12.X."
   pageno: 200
   content: ['Bla.','blabla.','blablablala', ... ]
 }
 2: { id: "12.XI."
   pageno: 202
   content: ['blabla.','blablablala.','Some more bla', ... ]
 }
}
```

I do know hot get all the `blas` into an array, trim them etc. but I am not sure how to split the headline off and how to look for the two rows which contain the id & the page number.

Right now I have:

```
var fs = require('fs');

try {
    var data = fs.readFileSync('files/file1.txt', 'utf8');
} catch(e) {
    console.log('Error:', e.stack);
}



var arr = data.split('-');

for(var i=0; i< arr.length;i++) {
  arr[i] = arr[i].replace(/\n/g, " ");
  arr[i] = arr[i].trim();
}
```

The headline I could probably get by just looking at the first element of the array, but if I split it by `-` first, I will have to search through my array then for the first `blas` of each chunk respectively. I can also not assume that `12.X. p. 200` will always be on the 3rd row and `12.XI. p. 202` in row no. 9, since that might change. Their values will also change, so I am a bit stuck.

Sorry if this is too much of a beginner problem, I am just starting out!

Comment: so your headlines will be in separate lines that do not contain '-' ?

Comment: is the above pattern is consistent meaning you will always have header, page no. and id(which will be together), content.

Comment: It is consistent, so it will always be: 1. `Header`, 2. `Page No. & Id`, 3. `Content`, then 4. `Page No. & Id` again, and 5. `Content` again. So the Header appears once, whereas everything else will appear twice.

Answer (score 0):

If your data is consistent this will work fine.

```
var linesData =data.split('\n\n')
var finalobj = {}; 
finalobj['headline'] = linesData[0].trim()
linesData.map((res, i) => {
    if (i!==0) {
        var lines = res.split('\n');
        var headersplit = lines[0].split(' ');
        var obj = {
            id: headersplit[0],
            pageno: +headersplit[2]
        }
        var contents = [];
        lines.map((line, j)=> {
            if(j!==0) {
                var newlinedata = line.split('-').map(m => m.trim()).filter(s => s!=='')
                contents = contents.concat(newlinedata);
            }
        })
        obj['content']=contents;
        finalobj[i]=obj;
    }
});
console.log(finalobj);
```